# Implying one generic type parameter from another in C# class

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class Demo<A, B>
    where A : IEquatable<A>
    where B : IList<A>, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Creating an instance is easy enough:

```
Demo<string, List<string>> test1 = new Demo<string, List<string>>();
// or more concisely:
var test2 = new Demo<string, List<string>>();
```

My question is: Can class `Demo` be rewritten without explicitly requiring type `A` when creating an instance, where it's implied somehow through type `B`? Something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
public class Demo<B>
    where B : IList<A>, new()
        where A : IEquatable<A>
....

var test = new Demo<List<string>>(); // Only one type parameter
```

It's not a big deal for the particular project I'm working on, but the repetition of type parameters needed to create an instance piqued my curiosity.

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the suggestions, it's clarified the problem a lot better for me. I suppose I could rephrase the question as: can a generic class access the generic type parameter of its constraint's generic type?

So is it possible to create something along the lines of:

```
public IMyInterface<T> where  T : IEquatable<T>...
public class myClass<A> where A : IMyInterface<B>, new()... // doesn't compile
```

...and access both `A` and `B` in my code? I suspect not.

Comment: its very intersting indeed. but I think it should know type B from A: `var test = new Demo<string>();`

Comment: Can I ask you why are you requiring two type parameters and not just one? Could you not just use a single type parameter (your `A`) and then just use `IList<A>` inside any method which requries it?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I'm not sure I understand. `var test = new Demo<string>();` won't compile as it currently stands.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma That's a very good point. My actual code uses a slightly more complicated interface than IList, but yes it makes sense. Let me try it out...

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Sorry, one of my methods needs to create an instance of the second type parameter (e.g. `B instance = new B()`). I *could* use a constructor dependency injection pattern I suppose, but that's just moving the repetition from one place to another.

Comment: Ok, from what I understand you are tightly bounded to the specific `IYourInterface` implementation. If possible you should try to see if you can loose the bound and, when needing to create an implementation, just create a *default* concrete class you already have, and keep returning the interface. If this is not feasible, I'm afraid your only chance is to rely on inheritance or static factory methods.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Yes, that does seem to be a good approach, thanks. Like I said, it's not a big deal for this project, I'm mostly just curious about the mechanics of how generics work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an intermediate interface that will do your type mappings between A and B

```
public interface IDemo<A, B> 
    where A : IEquatable<A>
    where B : IList<A>, new()
{

}
```

And then define your Demo class as such.

```
public class Demo<B> : IDemo<B, List<B>>
    where B : IEquatable<B> // This is required for this type definition
{

}
```

Which can then be used like you wanted

```
var demo = new Demo<string>();
```

Comment: Yes, it is an option. It would require a new subclass for every type `B` (one for `List<T>`, another for `SortedList<T>`, etc). I was curious whether it's possible to avoid that. `var test = new Demo<string, List<string>>();` can accomplish what I was looking for, so it's no big deal. Just wondering if generics could be a little more... co-operative with each other!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky to figure out without knowing the real content of the Demo class, but why would you need to consider the List as generic parameter ?

Why not simply

```
public class Demo<A> where A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public Demo()
    {
       DemoB = new List<A>();
    }

    public Demo(A demoA) : this()
    {
        DemoA = demoA;            
    }

    public A DemoA { get; }
    public IList<A> DemoB { get; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what concrete type `B` is going to be, only that it takes a generic type `A`. I'm only using `IList<A>` as an example, but suppose, instead of `new List<A>`, somebody needed to use a `SortedList<A>` for example?

Comment: Sorry but in this case, I guess you would have no choice but to deal with intermediary interfaces (or classes) as proposed in other answers, but I don't think this is very convenient and it can also make the code more complicated to read !

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much. Thanks for your input, like I said, it's not a big deal, just curious!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseDemo<A, B>
    where A : IEquatable<A>
    where B : IList<A>, new()
{
}

public class Demo<B> : BaseDemo<B, List<B>>
    where B : IEquatable<B> 
{
}
```

usage

```
var test2 = new Demo<string>();
```

see this working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tA8UIY)

Comment: you probably got downvoted because the same answer was already posted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that it requires a new subclass for each type `B`, whereas the question is related to picking up type `B`'s type parameter, if that makes sense? Sorry if I'm not explaining it very well!